# Segmentation Fault while dynamicaly adding widget in Qt

Tags: c++, qt

I was trying to add a QWidget while runtime in Qt but It is showing SIGSEV signal received from OS because of segmentation fault.
Here is my code:

//mainwindow.h

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QLabel>
#include <QLineEdit>
#include <QVBoxLayout>
#include <QtGui>

namespace Ui {
class MainWindow;
}

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MainWindow();

private slots:
    void on_pushButton_submit_clicked();

private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
    QLabel *label;
    QLineEdit *line_edit;
};

#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

//mainwindow.cpp

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}

void MainWindow::on_pushButton_submit_clicked()
{
    QString str = ui->lineEdit1->text();
    QString str1 =ui->lineEdit2->text();
    if(str=="rana"&&str1=="vivek")
    {
        label = new QLabel();
        label->setText("Success");
        MainWindow.layout->addWidget(label);
        label->show();
    }
    else
    {
        line_edit = new QLineEdit();
        line_edit->setText("Sorry");
        MainWindow.layout->addWidget(line_edit);
        line_edit->show();
    }
}
```

//main.cpp

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include <QApplication>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    MainWindow w;
    w.show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

I know that segmentation fault occurs due to dereferencing of a null pointer but i couldn't find where I have done that mistake.Any Suggestions?

Comment: Have you tried to debug? On which line exactly it happens ?

Comment: `MainWindow.layout->addWidget` it seems that your layout is NULL.

Comment: What is MainWindow, when used in MainWindow.layout

Comment: @BartoszKP In Qt, the `Ui::*` classes are auto-generated by the UI description compiler. It's unlikely that the problem is hiding there.

Comment: `MainWindow.layout->addWidget(label);` How does that even compile?

Comment: @SebastianRedl Long time no Qt. Sorry and thanks:)

Comment: @NemanjaBoric:I'm new to Qt programming.So how to remove that error.

Comment: It is showing error: Inferior stopped b/s it received sigsev.

Comment: Its very rude from the downvoter(experienced guy),everyone is not smart enough from very start to sort out all errors by himself.

Comment: `line_edit->show();` and `label->show();` not needed - both widgets are part of MainwWindow and will be shown as soon as MainWindow become visible.

Comment: @CowboY remove that famous line and add:  `ui->LayoutName->addWidget(widgetName);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe implementing in this way will make sense?

```
void MainWindow::on_pushButton_submit_clicked()
{
    QString str = ui->lineEdit1->text();
    QString str1 =ui->lineEdit2->text();

    QWidget *w = new QWidget(this);
    QVBoxLayout *layout = new QVBoxLayout; // creates a vertical layout

    if(str=="rana"&&str1=="vivek")
    {
        label = new QLabel(w);
        label->setText("Success");
        layout->addWidget(label);
    }
    else
    {
        line_edit = new QLineEdit(w);
        line_edit->setText("Sorry");
        layout->addWidget(line_edit);
    }
    w->setLayout(layout);
    setCentralWidget(w);
}
```

**UPDATE:**
QMainWindow already has a predefined layout, so it was needless to introduce a new one. The code above creates an intermediate widget and construct it using its own layout. Than the widget set as a central widget in the MainWindow.

Comment: This way it compiled but label didn't appear.Following problem was shown in application output:&"warning: GDB: Failed to set controlling terminal: Inappropriate ioctl for device\n"
QWidget::setLayout: Attempting to set QLayout "" on MainWindow "MainWindow", which already has a layout

Comment: @CowboY, well, I have updated the code by introducing new widget that added as a "central widget" in the main window.

Answer (score 5):

```
        MainWindow.layout->addWidget(label);
```

doesn't make a lot of sense - this should not even compile, as Sebastian noted.

First, make sure you have layout in the Ui file (I added one vertical layout named `verticalLayout`), so you have a layout where you will add widgets. You will have a pointer to it inside your `ui` object.

Now, just use `addWidget` on that layout and everything should work:

```
void MainWindow::on_pushButton_submit_clicked()
{
    QString str = ui->lineEdit1->text();
    QString str1 =ui->lineEdit2->text();
    if(str=="rana"&&str1=="vivek")
    {
        QLabel *label = new QLabel();
        label->setText("Success");
        ui->verticalLayout->addWidget(label);
        // label->show(); widgets will became the part of the MainWindow, as the addWidget
        //                will add them into the hierarchy. 
    }
    else
    {
        QLineEdit *line_edit = new QLineEdit();
        line_edit->setText("Sorry");
        ui->verticalLayout->addWidget(line_edit);
        // line_edit->show() 
    }
}
```

Note - `addWidget` will set the owner of the widget to be the layout, so the widget will be deleted on the destruction of the layout.

Comment: I added QLayout *layout; in my header file,but still it is showing error layout not a memeber of ui::MainWindow class.

Comment: You need to add it through the designer, so it becomes the part of the `ui::MainWindow` class.

Comment: @CowboY Just to explain what is `ui`.Basically, `ui::MainWindow` is automatically generated class by qt-designer. It is located in `ui_mainwindow.h` (you can read it). It holds everything you create by qt designer. So, you create an instance of it with `ui(new Ui::MainWindow)` and `ui->setupUi(this);` for `this` class. It means that when you create a layout in your c++ file by hand, you cannot access it with `ui`, because it(your created widget) is not part of `ui::MainWindow`

Comment: @CowboY read the explanation by the khajvah. The layout is not the member of MainWindow: `ui->verticalLayout->addWidget` <- here the `verticalLayout` is a member of `ui` object. Make sure you replace `verticalLayout` with the name you set in the designer (maybe just `layout`).

Comment: @khajvah and Nemanja: Thanks a lot.It was very helpfull.But I wanted to add my layout using QLayout but it didn't work.It showed error warning: GDB: Failed to set controlling terminal: Inappropriate ioctl for device\n" QWidget::setLayout: Attempting to set QLayout "" on MainWindow "MainWindow", which already has a layout.